# How to have clients' requests automatically dispatched to 10 different load-balancing machines, round-robin-style?

Tags: domain-name-system, load-balancing, round-robin

I know how to setup these solutions:

1. Let's say the website `www.example.com` has a *single machine* for it (IP 203.0.113.123), using a Linux + Apache server. It works if the bandwidth is not too high.
2. Let's say we now have **more and more requests for this website**, thus the computer with IP 203.0.113.123 will now **only be a load-balancing server**, dispatching the requests to many workers (other computers), which serve the actual webpages.

but I have a question about this case:

3. Let's say now there are sometimes peaks of **tens or hundreds of thousands of requests per second** for this website. Having a single load-balancing machine 203.0.113.123 is not possible anymore.

If we have 10 load-balancing machines: 203.0.113.123, 203.0.113.124, 203.0.113.125, 203.0.113.126, 203.0.113.127, ..., 203.0.113.132 (that dispatch the requests to tens of other workers), how to have the clients arrive to all of them, randomly / Round-robin-style?

The DNS records usually display only one A record, even for big well-known websites (see [here](https://dnschecker.org/all-dns-records-of-domain.php) the DNS records for Google, there is only one A record), such as:

```
www.example.com 3600    A   0   203.0.113.123
```

**How to make that clients' requests arrive to the ten machines randomly and not only 203.0.113.123?**

(Obviously, we don't want a single machine to dispatch the requests to the ten load-balancing machines, because then we would be back to case 2.)

Comment: There can be multiple A records for the same hostname. Try `dig stackoverflow.com
` or `nslookup stackoverflow.com`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS

Comment: @DusanBajic I tried for google.com, and there is only one A record. Also, even if there are multiple A records, how are they chosen? Won't most clients use the first one?

Comment: @DusanBajic Indeed `nslookup stackoverflow.com` shows four IP addresses. Do you think 4 load-balancing servers are enough for such a big website? (well in fact, it might not be so surprising, since the bandwidth is not so high, in comparison to video-sharing websites, etc.).  Note: `nslookup youtube.com` shows only one IP. So there is surely an internal mechanism to distribute the requests to many load-balancing servers, what is it?

Comment: For really huge sites, it is either geodns (see https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/youtube.com) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoDNS, https://jameshfisher.com/2017/02/08/how-does-geodns-work/) or  BGP anycast (https://serverius.net/bgp-anycast-dual-datacenter-using-1-ip-multiple-locations/, https://www.keycdn.com/support/anycast)

Comment: And for "Won't most clients use the first one", the answer is :"With each DNS response, the IP address sequence in the list is permuted."